# The quantity does not work correctly in the online store on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My site is a website for selling cards such as Google Play cards, Apple Play cards, and others. The problem I am facing is that after the payment process, the cards appear correctly but without a quantity. For example, it is assumed that if the customer buys five cards, five cards appear to him, but only one appears.

```
foreach ($cart->items as $key => $prod) {
    if (!empty($prod['item']['license']) && !empty($prod['item']['license_qty'])) {
        foreach ($prod['item']['license_qty'] as $ttl => $dtl) {
            $orderedQty = $prod['qty'];
            for ($i = 0; $i < $orderedQty; $i++) {
                if ($dtl != 0) {
                    $dtl--;
                    $produc = Product::findOrFail($prod['item']['id']);
                    $temp = $produc->license_qty;
                    $temp[$ttl] = $dtl;
                    $final = implode(',', $temp);
                    $produc->license_qty = $final;
                    $produc->update();
                    $temp = $produc->license;
                    $license = $temp[$ttl];
                    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
                    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
                    $cart->updateLicense($prod['item']['id'], $license);
                    Session::put('cart', $cart);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two problems appear to me. The first is that he always shows the customer only one card. The second is that the cards are deducted correctly from the back end, but only one card appears on the front, which is the last.
explain to you a little after the product On my site inside the product page, I can add cards as shown in the picture. The code that you sent performs two tasks. The first is to send the code to the purchase success page The second is that the code reduces the value of the card from the stock, or if it is not present in the stock, it searches for another card. prnt.sc/WT0pj7JsDVEM

Comment: don't put prints, but code!